# Syncing multiple unrelated components in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I have certain components which, when hovered, will need to highlight not just the element being hovered but also other completely unrelated components.

One way of doing this is forcing updates on the topmost container, but that performs very poorly once the number of elements starts growing to a significant amount, so my question is: Is there a way I could somehow "link" several components so that whenever one component updates, it notifies its related components? Another possibility that comes to mind is storing references to the component objects and accessing the `__self` field. But that doesn't look very idiomatic, so I was wondering whether there is another way?

Comment: They need to be related somehow through common parent. The question lacks the example that could describe your case. How do you know which component should be highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to hover multiple components on hover of one, you could probably maintain a state that is being set onHover of any of the components in the common parent of those components. Using this state you can add a class on those component

```
state= {
   hovered: false
}

onHover = () => {
    this.setState({hovered: true});
}

onHoverOut = () => {
    this.setState({hovered: false});
}
```

Now in the child components, you can make use of onMouseEnter

```
onMouseEnter = () => {
   this.props.onHover();
}

onMouseLeave = () => {
   this.props.onHoverOut();
}
```

and you can use the hovered value like

```
<div className={classnames({[hovered]: this.props.hovered})} />
```

Comment: But won't changing the state of the parent force a full re-render of the whole application? This is what I was already doing, just that instead of calling setState I was calling forceUpdate. Is there any advantage of doing so with just setState? I implemented a basic version of this and my application is still very slow.

Comment: I realized that with the setState approach I can implement "shouldComponentUpdate" to tell React when to update the components. Now only the elements for which the highlight state is really changed are re-rendered.

Comment: You can simply make use of PureComponent in React to implement the shouldComponentUpdate for you